# Modify XML having text more than one using Rails and Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I am looking for something which will modify the `.docx` file in Ruby. Here, in this code I have done with modification in xml file.

Only once element is modified , but wanna replace all the element `"FirstName"` with `"DEMONAME"`

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(IO.read('word/document.xml'))
doc.at('//text()[.="FirstName"]').content = 'DEMONAME'
File.open('word/document_modify.xml','w') do |f|
  f.puts doc
end
```

Please suggest some thing to modify whole document having 5 times or more times `FirstName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I got the solution to resolve this problem.

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(IO.read('word/document.xml'))
(doc/'//text()[.="FirstName"]').each do |field|
  doc.at('//text()[.="FirstName"]').content = 'DEMONAME'
end
```